# Get The Member Who Invited Bot

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to get the [`GuildMember`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.3.1/class/GuildMember) object of whoever invited the bot using the [`guildCreate`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/12.3.1/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate) event.

```js
const fetchedLogs = await message.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
   limit: 1,
   type: ''
})
```

Not sure if I'm on the right path, however, *if I am*, what argument do I pass for `type`?

Comment: type 28. https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/AuditLogAction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the code I use to find the user who invited the bot, which is good enough for my purposes

```
bot.on('guildCreate', (guild) => {
  console.log(`event guildCreate: ${guild.name} ${guild.id}`);
  guild.fetchAuditLogs({ limit: 1, type: 28 }) // type 28 is "add bot"
    .then(audit => {
      let userID = audit.entries.first().executor.id;
      // do something here
    })
    .catch(console.error);
});
```

Comment: Gives an error of `Missing Permissions`, Anyway to bypass?

Comment: bot needs a permission to access audit logs. make a new invite link that has the audit logs permission and invite the bot again